# Is the Reverse PTR record fine

Tags: domain-name-system, ptr-record

I've checked my email headers at http://mxtoolbox.com which says it is ok. But I'm not sure.

MY server's FQDN is host.tariffplansindia.com and for my server's IP( 23.239.30.81) the reverse PTR record resolves to tariffplansindia.com.

But all my emails have server name as host.tariffplansindia.com.

Do  23.239.30.81's reverse PTR need to resolve to host.tariffplansindia.com or is it ok with set currently(tariffplansindia.com )

**Email headers:**

```
Delivered-To: rag.rag22@gmail.com
Received: by 10.114.81.66 with SMTP id y2csp615139ldx;
        Mon, 17 Nov 2014 18:25:05 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.182.215.136 with SMTP id oi8mr27687082obc.18.1416277503115;
        Mon, 17 Nov 2014 18:25:03 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: 
Received: from host.tariffplansindia.com (tariffplansindia.com. [2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe73:2b08])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id q10si41713064obk.50.2014.11.17.18.25.02
        for 
        (version=TLSv1.1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Mon, 17 Nov 2014 18:25:02 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of rag22@host.tariffplansindia.com designates 2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe73:2b08 as permitted sender) client-ip=2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe73:2b08;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of rag22@host.tariffplansindia.com designates 2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe73:2b08 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=rag22@host.tariffplansindia.com
Received: by host.tariffplansindia.com (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id BA43713534; Tue, 18 Nov 2014 07:55:01 +0530 (IST)
To: rag.rag22@gmail.com
Subject: Content indianworkingwoman.org changed
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:checkforum.php
Message-Id: 
Date: Tue, 18 Nov 2014 07:55:01 +0530 (IST)
From: rag22@host.tariffplansindia.com (AccountA)
```

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is that your PTR record for the IP give out at least one hostname which resolves to the IP from which the mails came.  This is the PTR record check.

So, in your case, as long as `tariffplansindia.com` can resolve to 23.239.30.81, and `81.32.239.23.in-addr.arpa` resolves to `tariffplansindia.com.`, you're set.  If not, change it so it matches.

Answer (score 0):

Having the canonical hostname (FQDN) as the reverse dns `PTR` record is what is actually expected.

It's also worth noting that while the actual question only mentions `23.239.30.81` the included mail headers clearly show that this particular message was delivered over IPv6, using the address `2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe73:2b08`.

My recommendation would be to ensure that `host.tariffplansindia.com` (your hostname) has the appropriate `A` and `AAAA` records and to then change the `PTR` records at `81.30.239.23.in-addr.arpa` and `8.0.b.2.3.7.e.f.f.f.1.9.c.3.0.f.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.c.3.0.0.6.2.ip6.arpa` to match the FQDN.

Answer (score -1):

It is fine to have a reverse record which does not point exactly to the same name as your mailname (the one sent in EHLO command). Only very few senders (I would call them Nazi servers) would reject your mails. However note this is fairly more common for a server to check the target of your PTR record points to the same IP you send email from (the one it resolved the PTR from).
So in your case you should make sure tariffplansindia.com resolves to 23.239.30.81

Comment: which one - host.tariffplansindia.com or tariffplansindia.com should resolve to IP?

Comment: Both should... Can someone explain the down vote?